# sql: making a table structure for injections

Tags: sql, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I want to take the values from [this site](http://www.john.geek.nz/2009/01/sql-tips-list-of-countries/) for the country table in my database.

The problem is that they don't provide the table structure, so I have to create one, but I cannot get it right - my phpMyAdmin keeps displaying an error when I want to inject the data into the table I created below:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NUMERIC, alpha3, name, officialName) VALUES ('004','AFG','Afghanistan','Afghan' at line 1

```
--
-- Table structure for table `countrytable`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `countrytable` (
  `NUMERIC` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `alpha3` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `officialName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I think my table structure is incorrect. How can I fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try all varchar fields to get the data in since all fields are in quotes in the string you have.

Answer (score 1):

`NUMERIC` is reserved word in mysql 
add in back-tick or quote it -> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 0):

`alpha3` should be a varchar(3) (or larger), not an int(11).